# How to connect Teradata with Python in Linux?

Tags: python, odbc, teradata, pyodbc, unixodbc

**I am trying to connect TD with Python in Linux.**

I got this working on Windows:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=<HOST IP>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<UID>;QUIETMODE=YES;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = 'select * from table_name'
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()
print rows
```

Steps I followed to do it on Linux:

1. Install pyodbc
2. Install TeraGSS, tdicu, cliv2, piom, tdodbc
3. Run the following:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=<HOST IP>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<UID>;QUIETMODE=YES;')
```

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Am I missing any configuration step after installations?

Environment:

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

Comment: [This](http://crashthatch.tumblr.com/post/66957708538/teradata-odbc-connection-using-python-on-ubuntu) might be a good guide to check whether your setup is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you pass as DRIVER needs to

a) the name of a driver in your odbcinst.ini file or

b) the full path to the ODBC driver shared object.

As you are using the first method I'd suggest you run `odbcinst -j` to find out where your odbcinst.ini file is located and check if you've defined any drivers.

Driver sections start with [MYDRIVERNAME] so you should have a section starting [Teradata] and it should contain a keyword/value pair of something like driver = /path/to/teradata/driver/shared_object. If you have defined a [Teradata] driver then check the shared object pointed to with the "driver" keyword exists, is readable/executable by you and has no unresolved dependencies (run ldd on it).